# Systemd error : Executable path is not absolute

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, systemd, upstart, init-script

I have the following below code of systemd.

```
[Unit]
Description=start RCC logger server process
Requires=rcc-drbd.service rcc_check_locked_scr.service s96rcc.service
After=rcc-drbd.service rcc_check_locked_scr.service s96rcc.service

[Service]
ExecStart= exec /var/RCC/RCClogger.sh
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

where i try to run it, i get the below error.

```
Mar 23 04:45:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: 
[/etc/systemd/system/rcc_logger.service:7] Executable path is not absolute, 
ignoring: exec /v...ogger.sh
Mar 23 04:45:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rcc_logger.service lacks 
both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

I know it is because of no absolute path of exec command, but since exec is not available as binary i cannot use absolute path for it.
How to make this ExecStart run?

Comment: remove `exec`, it isn't required (script should contain hashbang to invoke shell)

Answer (score 20):

You can't use `exec` in a systemd service unit configuration.
`exec` is a shell built-in and cannot be called directly from the filesystem (it doesn't reside on the filesystem) -- `type exec` and `whereis exec` will show you that.
Use the shell they're written in.

For example, if it's a `bash` script, you can run the script like this:

```
bash /var/RCC/RCClogger.sh
```

Now, `bash` is an executable and does have an absolute path: `/bin/bash`. Your ExecStart will look like the following:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash /var/RCC/RCClogger.sh
```

---

Another way is to simply add a [`shebang`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to the beginning of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
... script code ...
```

This tells the operating system to run the file with the specified interpreter, `/bin/bash` in this case.

After that simply make your script executable:

```
chmod +x /var/RCC/RCClogger.sh
```

And use it directly as the `ExecStart`:

```
ExecStart=/var/RCC/RCClogger.sh
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you're right about my choice of wording, fixed.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Its instructional as well as accurate. Solved my issue. Thank you @Fanatique

Answer (score -2):

The "EXecStart=" needs an absolute path to start the service. Get the full path to your .sh file and append it to ExecStart statement.

Again "manpage" will give you detailed info.

Comment: The original poster is using an absolute path, as can be seen from his code snippet. The issue is well explained in the other answer.